# What Exactly is Axis of A Solenoid? How does placing a soft Iron Core Along The Axis increase its Strength of Magnetic Field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance

I have trouble understanding what is meant by axis of solenoid.

According to textbooks placing a soft iron core "along the axis of solenoid" increases the strength of the magnetic field of the solenoid as the soft iron has a high magnetic permeability

Can someone explain how this works ^

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. It is hard to understand what you are asking. Please clarify exactly what is confusing you about the many images that you will find online showing what the axis of a solenoid is if you simply search online for "axis of a solenoid".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The axis of a solenoid is its geometrical axis.

As a first approximation, the magnetic field in the region of space "inside" a solenoid is uniform, and equal to

$\mathbf{B} = \mu \dfrac{N}{L} i \, \mathbf{\hat{z}}$,

being:

- $\mu$ the magnetic permeability of the medium "inside" the solenoid,
- $\frac{N}{L} = \dfrac{\text{n. windings of the
     solenoid}}{\text{length of the solenoid}}$ the density of windings
  per unit length,
- and $i$ the electric current in the wire.

With the same current, if you put a ferromagnetic medium inside the solenoid, the magnitude of the magnetic field increases, since $\mu = \mu_r \mu_0 \gg \mu_0$, with $\mu_0$ the permeability of vacuum as a good approximation of permeability of air, and with relative permeability of order $\mu_r = 10^2 \div 10^5$ for ferromagnetic materials,

$B^{ferro} = \mu_r\mu_0 \dfrac{N}{L} i = \mu_r B^{air} = ( 10^2 \div 10^5 ) \cdot B^{air}$.